# SSL cipher suite usage statistics based on captured data

Tags: web-server, tls

Is there a reasonable method of building SSL cipher usage statistics based on captured packets?

Let's say my web server supports a set of ciphers and I would like to find out how many clients negotiate each cipher suite.

Comment: the answer will be server OS-specific as well as web server-specific - voting to migrate to serverfault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**.  If you've got **captured packets**, simply extract the negotiated cipher from the [Server Hello handshake packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3):

> cipher_suite
>
> ```
>   The single cipher suite selected by the server from the list in
>   ClientHello.cipher_suites.  For resumed sessions, this field is
>   the value from the state of the session being resumed.
> ```

The packet itself can be easily identified, and the selected cipher is in a set location within it, easy enough to parse.  So capture the first few packets of all your SSL connections, extract the cipher chosen, and you've got what you're looking for.

The idea was interesting enough that I decided to try it.  With a little hacking and slashing I was able to adapt a Python script to do it:

```
$ ./parser.py random2.pcap | sort -u
TLS 1.0 0x00,0x14
TLS 1.2 0x00,0x2f
TLS 1.2 0x00,0x30
$
```

With that info, you can correlate the cipher suite IDs against the [TLS Cipher Suite Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-5) from IANA:

```
$ ./parser.py random2.pcap  | sort -u | awk '{print $3}' | grep -if - ~/Downloads/tls-parameters-4.csv 
"0x00,0x14",TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA,Y,[RFC4346]
"0x00,0x2F",TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,Y,[RFC5246]
"0x00,0x30",TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,Y,[RFC5246]
$
```

Here's the code.  It's a real strip-down of [TLS Client Hello Tools](https://github.com/pquerna/tls-client-hello-stats) so if you want to play with it, consider going back to there for a less drastic version (and bear in mind the original focuses on the Client Hello whereas we care about the Server Hello).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Hack-and-slash derived from https://github.com/pquerna/tls-client-hello-stats

import os, sys, dpkt
TLS_HANDSHAKE = 22

def pcap_reader(fp):
    return dpkt.pcap.Reader(fp)

def grab_negotiated_ciphers(cap):
    for ts, buf in cap:
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        if not isinstance(eth.data, dpkt.ip.IP):
            continue
        ip = eth.data
        if not isinstance(ip.data, dpkt.tcp.TCP):
            continue

        tcp = ip.data
        if (tcp.dport != 443 and tcp.sport != 443) or (len(tcp.data) <= 0) or (ord(tcp.data[0]) != TLS_HANDSHAKE):
            continue

        records = []
        try:
            records, bytes_used = dpkt.ssl.TLSMultiFactory(tcp.data)
        except dpkt.ssl.SSL3Exception, e:
            continue
        except dpkt.dpkt.NeedData, e:
            continue

        if len(records) <= 0:
            continue

        for record in records:
            # TLS handshake only
            if (record.type == 22 and len(record.data) != 0 and ord(record.data[0]) == 2):
                try:
                    handshake = dpkt.ssl.TLSHandshake(record.data)
                except dpkt.dpkt.NeedData, e:
                    continue
                if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSServerHello):
                    ch = handshake.data
                    print '%s\t0x%0.2x,0x%0.2x' %(dpkt.ssl.ssl3_versions_str[ch.version], (ch.cipher_suite&0xff00)>>8, ch.cipher_suite&0xff)
                else:
                    continue

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
        print "Tool to grab and print TLS Server Hello cipher_suite"
        print ""
        print "Usage: parser.py <pcap file>"
        print ""
        sys.exit(1)

    with open(argv[1], 'rb') as fp:
        capture = pcap_reader(fp)
        stats = grab_negotiated_ciphers(capture)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Hypothetically a client could renegotiate a different cipher suite later, but that probably never happens.

Comment: @gowenfawr Many thanks for this great answer! I edited your code as you made couple of mistakes in bitwise calculation: (1) you only need to shift 8 bits (not 16); (2) you need parentheses so the resulting number is shifted, but not the mask itself. So, instead of `ch.cipher_suite&0xff00>>16`, we need `(ch.cipher_suite&0xff00)>>8`
 
_please either accept my editing or correct the code yourself_ Thanks!

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks @Mike, edit accepted.  (The top bits of the cipher suite are uuuuuuuusually 0, so the bug wasn't obvious in testing).

Comment: @gowenfawr -- hehe, after I noticed someone had allegedly negotiated TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x002a), I started to investigate it and finally found out that it was actually TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02a) :)
I bet there is a similar case in the example you gave -- I don't think you captured anyone negotiating "0x00,0x14" (TLS_DHE_RSA_*EXPORT*_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA), rather it was "0x0C,0x14" (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to find out what cipher suites your web server's clients are using, there may be easier methods.

For example, Nginx's ssl module has [several variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) like `$ssl_cipher` and `$ssl_protocol`, which [you can](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) [also log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format):

```
log_format ssl '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status '
               '$body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
               '$ssl_protocol $ssl_cipher';

access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl.log ssl;
```

```
2001:db8::1 - - [27/Mar/2015:21:11:04 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200
12345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

(By the way, it's safe to use that log format for HTTP traffic too. The ssl variables will just show up as `-`.)